# Flash ActionScript FLVplayback SeekBar Noise

Tags: flash, seekbar, flvplayback

my issue is with flash FLVplakback control with a seekBar attached to it.

example can be found [here](http://www.guygar.com/flowplayer/example/player.html).

for some unknown reason when i try to rewind using the seekbar, it produces a loud noise at the start.

whereas if i let it play out the entire movie (mp4) and then play again using the play button it does not produce such noise.

in case i rewind using the seebBar after playback has completed even then it does not produce the noise.

i would help and advise regarding what is causing this noise and how to get rid of it, please?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried several versions of the MP4 movie im using and it seems to be a audio length issue rather than a flash issue.

the original sample plays fine, it is when i extract the audio to do effects on it and then when i save it as a combined mp4 the noise sneaks in.

im using Adobe Audition and thought it would take care to save the audio with exact parameters as the source!

thank you.